Elementary questions on motives
Motives are objects that appear in algebraic geometry, which is closely related to algebraic cycles. It was considered by Grothendieck, and developed notably by Deligne, Voevodsky etc.
I have the following questions on them.
①Do we have a proof that abelian varieties and tori are motives? Do we have a theory on the category of objects consisting of motives and algebraic varieties?
②How abelian varieties and motives of abelian varieties are different even though abelian varieties themselves are motives? Why are abelian varieties called homology or cohomology of dimension 1?
③Motives are direct factors of cohomology, but I do not find any definition of motives using cohomology. I know their definition using hodge cycles and algebraic cycles. Are all motives obtained as direct factors of cohomology?
Thank you for your answers.

Perhaps you should start looking at classical motives and the papers by Demazure, Manin, Kleiman, Scholl and others.

It should also be noted that there are many (inequivalent) notions of motives, e.g. Chow motives, Nori motives, André motives, Voevodsky motives, etcetera. In all of these, every smooth projective variety $X$ has an associated motive, but $X$ is not a motive. You are probably thinking of Deligne's 1-motives, which is some ad hoc definition that tries to capture "$H^1$-phenomena" using abelian varieties, algebraic tori, and finitely generated free abelian groups. I am not aware of a generalisation of this notion to $n$-motives for $n > 1$.

In a way, motives currently function like a philosophy rather than a theory, and each of the definitions used in the literature satisfies some of the desired properties, while other properties might be conjectural or false. There is no single unconditional theory of motives.

Actually, a semi-abelian variety A represents a homotopy invariant sheaf with transfers, and this gives a Voevodsky motive that is distinct from the motive of A. Yet I would rather suggest you to start from some "classical" motives; they are easier. Alternatively, you may try to read about 1-motives.

@MikhailBondarko Thank you for your comments.

Well, as Mikhail Bondarko pointed out, there is no fully self contained theory of the motives. But let me add a few things.
Generally one considers a cohomology functor $h$ from some category of schemes (like smooth, projective…) $\mathfrak{C}$ to the category of $\mathbb{Z}$ modules.
$$h: \mathfrak{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\text-\mathrm{Mod}.$$
Grothendieck's idea is then to introduce a motivic category $\mathcal{M}$, such that we have a motive functor $M:\mathfrak{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ and
a realization $r:\mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\text-\mathrm{Mod}$, with
$h = r \circ M$ i.e. the cohomology functor factors through $\mathcal{M}$.
The ingenious observation is now that in $\mathcal{M}$ the object $M(X)$ might decompose into summands of smaller motives.
The way $M(X)$ decomposes is an additional information about $X$, which can not be seen when just looking at $h(X)$.
If $h$ is the Chow functor (with integer or $\mathbb{F}_p$ coefficients)
and we are over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$, we consider the category of Chow motives $\mathcal{M}_k$ and if $X$ is a projective, homogeneous $G$-variety, for $G$ being an algebraic group over $k$, then the motivic decomposition still depends
on many invariants of $G$ (or more precise a $G$-torsor). In fact, the motivic decomposition is an invariant itself.
Let's take $G$ to be a Spin group and $X = G/P_1$, for $P_1$ the first maximal parabolic subgroup of $G$. Then $X$ is known to be a smooth, projective quadric.
Its motive is totally decomposable if and only if $G$ is split.
Otherwise there's an incredible amount of possible motivic decompositions of $X$, depending on its dimension etc.
You may now realize the issue with your questions.
What cohomology theory we are considering?
What motivic category are we working in?
Is $k$ algebraically closed (in this case Chow motives of algebraic groups are known and not really interesting for example)?

How do you number the maximal parabolic subgroups?

In Bourbaki enumeration. Also, there are two ways of defining what one means by $G/P_i$. One means to mod out the subgroup generated by $\omega_i$ i.e. a group generated by one simple root. The other one is to mod out the subgroup generated by all simple roots except $\omega_i$. My notation is the second one. This means $X_1$ is isotropic iff the equation defined by some quadratic form $q$ has a non trivial solution. Sorry for being too imprecise, but the point of my post was illustrating the manifoldness of the motivic world.

Considering its place in algebraic geometry, are you sure the point wasn’t to illustrate the variety of the motivic world?
